# How to update chart (anyChart Android) with new data from web service?

Tags: java, android, anychart

I have a cartesian-column chart and I need to refresh the chat with new data from a web service, it works fine the first time but after receiving new data the chart "fuses" the old and new data for a second, then flashes back and shows the old data

Here I clean my DataEntry and call my soap, this is done inside a function that is called from a button

```
 dataGraf=new ArrayList<>(); 
 new acIndicadores.call_SOAP().execute();
```

Soap ask for the info and add it to my DataEntry (the only important part here is the last line), I've settled logs so I know my DataEntry is receiving the data that I need.

```
 for(int y=0; y<NewDataSet.getPropertyCount(); y++)
{
   gfVentas = (SoapObject) NewDataSet.getProperty(y);
   if (gfVentas.getPropertyCount()==3)
   {
      if(Integer.parseInt(gfVentas.getProperty("hora").toString())==i)
      {
         vent=vent+Double.parseDouble(gfVentas.getProperty("Venta").toString());
      }

   }
   else
   {
     if(Integer.parseInt(gfVentas.getProperty("hora").toString())==i)
       {
        cob=cob+Double.parseDouble(gfVentas.getProperty("Venta").toString());
       }

   }
   dataGraf.add(new CustomDataEntry(Integer.toString(i), vent,cob));
}
```

Finally, I call this function from inside an onPostExecute so I know the SOAP-function is over and my data is in the DataEntry

```
 public void setgraph()
    {
        Set set = Set.instantiate();
        set.data(dataGraf);

        Mapping series1Data = set.mapAs("{ x: 'x', value: 'value' }");
        Mapping series2Data = set.mapAs("{ x: 'x', value: 'value2' }");

        cartesian.column(series1Data);
        cartesian.column(series2Data);
        anyChartView.setChart(cartesian);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I just moved

```
anyChartView.setChart(cartesian);
```

to my

```
onCreate()
```

and that solved the problem, I don't really know why but I'll take it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to clean the DataEntry. You can simply override it with new data and apply it to the existing chart. For details, check [this comment](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android/issues/147#issuecomment-598530371).

Answer (score 0):

cartesian.removeAllSeries();
and fill new Data it works